# Transforming (unpivoting) table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns `CompanyName`, `ReportingCurrencyAmount`, `ReportingCurrencyCode`, `TransactionCurrencyAmount` and `TransactionCurrencyCode`:

[image]

I would like to transform the table to something like this:

[image]

Comment: Hint: `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Im prety noob in SQL and hint is not enough unfortuently

Comment: It is enough, if you spend some time. Learning by doing!

Comment: Hi - please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Does the DBMS support UNPIVOT and, if it does, what did you learn and what issues are you facing having read the relevant documentation?

Comment: I think UNION ALL worked well. Im working in SSMS